# Проблемы производительности после нормализации базы mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, нормализация-данных

Есть таблица заказов orders и таблица статусов `orders_status` в которой хранится `id`, `order_id`, `status_id`, `date`
У каждого заказа, к примеру, до 10 статусов, таким образом получается что бы взять все статусы мне нужно сделать 10 `join`, но это занимает много времени при составлении отчета по большому количеству заказов. Можно ли как-то избежать большой нагрузки из-за большого количества join к одной таблице или только путем денормализации?
мои попытки решения с множественным join

```
SELECT *,
       s1.date AS status_1,
       s2.date AS status_2
FROM orders o
       JOIN orders_status s1
         ON s1.status_id = 1
            AND s1.order_id = o.id
       JOIN orders_status s2
         ON s2.status_id = 2
            AND s2.order_id = o.id
```

и так далее

Comment: Зачем это 10 джойнов-то?

Comment: зачем 10  join, почему не 1?

Comment: Как я могу получить все пары (status_id, date) одним join. Если это возможно, то это бы и было решением, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: покажите свои попытки решения в виде запроса

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: не понятно почему именно date вы называете статусом? может покажите определение своих таблиц и желаемый резульатт запроса?

Comment: если вам надо развернуть строки вашей таблицы со статусами в столбцы результирующего запроса, то используйте case и group by

Comment: в этом случае я не могу выбрать статус за определенный период к примеру  WHERE MAX(CASE WHEN s.status_id = 2 THEN s.date END) > '2021-01-01'  получается для сортировки по каждому статусу все равно придется делать свой JOIN?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так делается то, о чем писал @Konst в комментарии

```
SELECT
  o.*,
  MAX(CASE WHEN s.status_id = 1 WHEN s.date END) as status_1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN s.status_id = 2 WHEN s.date END) as status_2
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN orders_status s ON s.order_id=o.id
GROUP BY o.*
```

Comment: Спасибо, вам и @Konst, сейчас попробую, надеюсь будет быстрее)

Comment: проблема в том, что я не могу добавить критерий WHERE MAX(CASE WHEN s.status_id = 2 THEN s.date END) > '2021-01-01' к примеру, так что не подходит. Если же обернуть этот запрос в другой селект, то поиск будет долгим, без индексов

Comment: @Vadim_Tur, если отсев по одному статусу, то можно обойтись одним дополнительным JOIN'ом или даже EXISTS'ом

Comment: @Vadim_Tur, результат группировки нужно проверять не в WHERE, а в HAVING, который пишется ниже GROUP BY: `HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN s.status_id = 2 THEN s.date END) > '2021-01-01'`